# Why OBJECT_DEPENDS leads cycly error with Ninja generator?

Tags: c++, cmake, ninja

I need to make a hack in my CMake project. With this hack one of sources files must be compiled before any other files. It works with Makefile generator. But with Ninja generator I get error `ninja: error: dependency cycle:`. I tried to find any info how to fix this but no success.

**Simplified `CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

project(pchtest CXX)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" "pch.cpp" "pch.h" "pch_dummy.cpp")

set_source_files_properties(pch.cpp PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/pchtest.dir/pch_dummy.cpp.o)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/pch.h.gch
    COMMAND mv ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/pchtest.dir/pch.cpp.o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/pch.h.gch
    COMMAND cp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/pchtest.dir/pch_dummy.cpp.o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/pchtest.dir/pch.cpp.o
    COMMAND touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/pch.h.gch

    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/pchtest.dir/pch.cpp.o
    COMMENT "Copy PCH"
)

set_source_files_properties(main.cpp PROPERTIES OBJECT_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/pch.h.gch)
```

**Error:**

```
ninja: error: dependency cycle: CMakeFiles/pch.h.gch -> CMakeFiles/pchtest.dir/pch.cpp.o -> CMakeFiles/pchtest.dir/pch_dummy.cpp.o -> cmake_object_order_depends_target_pchtest -> CMakeFiles/pch.h.gch
```

So how to fix this?